# Eclipse RCP disable a view from a dialog

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a simple RCP application. I have a perspective and three views added to it. Initially one of the view will be disabled for the users. There is a toolbar item which launches a dialog. User authenticates himself in the dialog. After successful authentication, I want to make the view editable. I could get the reference of that specific view in my dialog.But I dont know how to enable it. I could not use selection listener as I am not selecting anything. Also I saw an example about using activities extension. But that opens/closes the view and not just enable/disable it. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you, you want to show the view in one of two states: either disabled if the user is not authenticated, or enabled when the user has been authenticated.

This is actually pretty easy :-) and I have made a small example application for you that illustrates the technique: [so-edi.zip](http://www.gdriveurl.com/?idl=613442389753&out=2)

**UPDATED** with new link

Comment: The link is broken.  Do you have a mirror?

Comment: While a full demo application is nice additional info, simply explaining the answer directly and providing a short code snippet is much more important. Your zip has ~400 lines of code for an answer that can be explained in one sentence: Add enablement accessors to the ViewPart implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In RCP 3.x you have to expose the View's Control's enabled state in your implementation of ViewPart:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

public class View extends ViewPart {
    private Control control;

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        control = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        control.setEnabled(enabled);
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return control.getEnabled()
    }
}
```